# @JsonValue annotation in Kotlin's enum class' value property

Tags: jackson, kotlin

I'm unable to apply the Jackson's `@JsonValue` annotation on the value parameter of enum class:

```
enum class CancellationReason(@JsonValue val code: String) {
    CUSTOMER_RESIGNED("20"),
    ERRORS_IN_FOO("21"),
    ERRORS_IN_BAR("24");
}
```

The error message states: `This annotation in not applicable to target 'value parameter'`. What's the problem?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can upgrade `jackson-module-kotlin` to version 2.9.0, and the error will be gone, because the `@JsonValue` annotation gets a target `FIELD` in that version.

Alternatively, fix that by specifying the [annotation use-site target](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/annotations.html#annotation-use-site-targets) by adding `@get:`:

```
enum class CancellationReason(@get:JsonValue val code: String) {
    CUSTOMER_RESIGNED("20"),
    ERRORS_IN_FOO("21"),
    ERRORS_IN_BAR("24");
}
```

Comment: Thanks, adding `@JsonValue` before the val in constructor of the enum class worked!

Answer (score 0):

As per this [document](https://tedblob.com/enum-in-kotlin/), you can serialize the enum constant (enum object) as Json in Kotlin by annotating the enum property with @JsonValue or @JsonFormat (if you use jackson library version < 2.9).
As hotkey mentioned, upgrade your Jackson library to 2.9.0. Alternatively you can use @JsonFormat annotation

```
enum class Event(@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.OBJECT) val event: String) {
    START("start"),
    END("end"),
    RESCHEDULE("rescheduled")
}
```