# spring failed to convert from type String to enum

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, http, openapi

I am currently trying to pass some sorting parameters through http request, so my controller got sort objects as a parameter that looks like this:

```
/**
* 
* Values: ASC,DESC
*/
enum class Sort(val value: kotlin.String) {

    @JsonProperty("created:ASC") ASC("created:ASC"),
    @JsonProperty("created:DESC") DESC("created:DESC")
}
```

that enum class generated with openapi,
I need to receive that parameter like this `created:ASC`, but it only if I send `ASC` or `DESC`

can't get my head on why it doesn't work, I thought `@JsonProperty` would be enough and it acutally is for another similar controller

the exception I get:

```
org.springframework.web.server.ServerWebInputException: 400 BAD_REQUEST "Type mismatch."

Caused by: org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to convert from type [java.lang.String] to type [@io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.Parameter @jakarta.validation.Valid @org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam com.my.app.api.Sort] for value 'created:ASC'


Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No enum constant com.my.app.api.Sort.created:ASC
    at java.base/java.lang.Enum.valueOf(Enum.java:273)
```

I use

```
spring-boot = 3.0.3,
kotlin = "1.8.0",
openapi = "7.0.0-beta"
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you're looking for `@JsonValue` instead of `@JsonProperty`.
As described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47099769/14436662 you can add the `@JsonValue` property to the enum constructor.
So your enum would look like this:

```
enum class Sort(@JsonValue val value: kotlin.String) {

    ASC("created:ASC"),
    DESC("created:DESC")
}
```

The `@JsonValue` also ensures that the response will also be parsed to the value inside the enum and not the enum constant name itself.